# Optimization routine giving error in autoencode function in autoencoder package

Tags: r, optimization, autoencoder

I am trying to run autoencoder by function `autoencode` from package `autoencoder` in R. I am putting min-max transformed data into it, but I get this error:

> Error in optim(par = theta, fn = J.theta, gr = grad.theta.J, method =
>   optimizer,  :  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

and my code looks like this:

```
ae = autoencoder::autoencode(train, test, N.hidden = 40 , unit.type = "logistic", 
                         rescale.flag=F, epsilon=0.1, lambda = 1, beta = 1, rho = 1, 
                         optim.method = "BFGS")
```

It is giving similar error also with other optim.method. 
What could cause that and how to solve this problem?

EDIT: I have tried to change rescale.flag from FALSE to TRUE and put into it data on the original scale and I got the same error.

Comment: Side-note: use `TRUE` and `FALSE`, don’t use `T` and `F`. The latter are *variables* that can be overridden.

Comment: I had the same problem and it turned out it was missing values (NAs) that were causing it. Could this be the case for you as well?

Comment: @agrei for sure not, I have treated missing values before, I have imputed them by the mean value of the particular variable.

Comment: I see. Do you think you could provide a minimum (un)workable example data to reproduce the error?